# C++ Smart pointer in a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to write this as a template parameter:

```
template <class T>
struct FooStruct {

    template <void F(std::unique_ptr<T> Object)>
    void FooMethod()
    {
        //....
    }

};
```

Then an error comes up:

```
error C2993: 'std::unique_ptr<T>' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'Object'
```

This approach works fine:

```
template <class T>
struct FooStruct {

    template <class UT,void F(UT Object)>
    void FooMethod()
    {
        //....
    }

};
```

If I pass `std::unique_ptr<Person>` in `UT` parameter in `FooMethod()` then everything works fine.

Is there a special way to pass in smart pointers as template parameters?

Comment: Did you include `<memory>` before the definition of `FooStruct`?

Comment: I guess the answer is: `template <void F(std::unique_ptr<T>)>` is legal. It decays to `template <void (*F)(std::unique_ptr<T>)>` as per [temp.param]/8, and *pointer to function* is allowed as the type for a non-type template parameter as per [temp.param]/4. You might have run into a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that `Object` was causing the problem, this seemed to work:

```
template <void(std::unique_ptr<T>)>
```

Then I just had to add an identified to the function like so:

```
template <void(*F)(std::unique_ptr<T>)>
```

Comment: AFAIK `Object` should be allowed, although it's of no use here.